# React.js state not getting updated to the current value

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Can someone help me with below code of React.js?

**Issue:** The state value of responseCount is not getting set after we get response from api submitPulseResponse.
Basically I have a counter which needs to get updated and shown on UI after the API is hit and API response gives me new updated total value to be shown on UI using responseCount state.
**For example:** If the current counter value is 5 post the vote is given the counter should increase based upon the value which I'll receive from submitPulseResponse function api response's total value
but instead it does not get updated with the value from response it still remains the same which was before casting the vote. I doubt that it maybe because of asynchronous nature of state updates in React.

I consulted staff engineer and he asked me to use callback function to update your state value.

CODE: https://privatebin.support-tools.com/?b71c49e84cfb9da1#Lb9G6a6FAJ4FL79m3S60Fm9YPMJDnjK0TjktRmn/tC8=

I am expecting the responseCount value to have an updated count from api response and only set that value to the state and display the value in the counter.

CODE:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import './PulseCheck.scss';
import { handleEventsForAnalytics } from '../../utils/helper';
import eventBus from '../../utils/eventBus';
import pulseIcon from '../../assets/images/icons/Medflix/pulse.svg';
import counterIcon from '../../assets/images/icons/Medflix/counter.svg';
import { submitPulseResponse } from '../../services/service';

const PulseCheck = ({
  question,
  options = [],
  page,
  variant,
  data,
  eachData,
  pulseData,
  toolTipText,
}) => {
  const [responseCount, setResponseCount] = useState(0);
  const [showGraph, setShowGraph] = useState(false);
  const [optionOnePercent, setOptionOnePercent] = useState(0);
  const [optionTwoPercent, setOptionTwoPercent] = useState(0);
  const [cookies] = useCookies(['UserData']);
  const [hasVoted, setHasVoted] = useState(false);
  const [responseSubmitted, setResponseSubmitted] = useState(false); // New state to track response submission

  const token = cookies?.UserData?.token;
  const objectId = cookies?.UserData?.ObjectID;
  const isUserLoggedIn = !!token && !!objectId; // Check if user is logged in
  const currentNewsId = eachData?.fields?.Id?.value || eachData?.Id;
  const votedNewsIds = cookies.UserData?.VotedNewsIds?.split(',') || [];

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if user has already voted
    const hasUserVoted = votedNewsIds.includes(String(currentNewsId));

    if (pulseData && Array.isArray(pulseData.data)) {
      // Find the pulse data for the current news ID
      const currentPulseData = pulseData.data.find((d) => d.newsId === String(currentNewsId));
      if (currentPulseData) {
        if (hasUserVoted === true) {
          updateGraphPercentages(currentPulseData);
          setShowGraph(true);
        }

        setResponseCount(currentPulseData.total);
      }
    }
    // setHasVoted(true); // Assuming presence of pulseData indicates voting status
  }, [token, pulseData, currentNewsId, votedNewsIds, cookies.UserData?.VotedNewsIds]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('responseCount has been updated to:', responseCount);
    // Any other logic you want to execute after responseCount is updated
  }, [responseCount]); // This effect depends on `responseCount`

  // New useEffect hook to handle graph rendering upon response submission
  useEffect(() => {
    if (responseSubmitted && pulseData) {
      setShowGraph(true);
      setResponseSubmitted(false);
    }
  }, [responseSubmitted, pulseData]); // Depend on responseSubmitted and pulseData

  // Function to update the graph percentages
  const updateGraphPercentages = (pulseData) => {
    const optionOneCount = pulseData.optionOneCount;
    const optionTwoCount = pulseData.optionTwoCount;
    const total = pulseData.total;
    if (total > 0) {
      const calculatedOptionOnePercent = ((optionOneCount / total) * 100).toFixed(1);
      const calculatedOptionTwoPercent = ((optionTwoCount / total) * 100).toFixed(1);
      setOptionOnePercent(calculatedOptionOnePercent);
      setOptionTwoPercent(calculatedOptionTwoPercent);
      console.log('Total value: ', total);
      setResponseCount(total);

      // If one of the options has all the votes (100%), set the other option's percentage to null
      if (calculatedOptionOnePercent === 100) {
        setOptionTwoPercent(null);
      } else if (calculatedOptionTwoPercent === 100) {
        setOptionOnePercent(null);
      }
    }
  };
  console.log('Response-count: ', responseCount);

  // Function to handle analytics event
  const handleClick = (event, ev, item_location, type, title, url) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let analyticsData = {
      type,
      title,
      url,
    };
    handleEventsForAnalytics(event, ev, analyticsData, item_location);
  };

  // Function to handle response and show graph
  const handleResponse = async (event, option) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check if the user is not logged in
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
      // Prevent further action and show the login popup
      eventBus.dispatch('validateUser', { isLoggedIn: false, Msg: 'NotSignedIn' });
      return;
    }

    if (hasVoted) {
      // If the user has already voted, don't allow voting
      console.log('User has already voted');
      return;
    }

    const newsId = eachData?.fields?.Id?.value || eachData?.Id || pulseData?.data?.newsId;

    if (!newsId) {
      // Handle the case where newsId is not defined
      console.error('No valid newsId to send');
      return;
    }

    const selectedOption = option === options[0] ? 'OPTION_ONE' : 'OPTION_TWO';

    // Payload to be sent to the backend
    const payload = {
      newsId: newsId,
      objectId: objectId,
      selectedOption: selectedOption,
    };

    // Use the service function to send the payload to the backend
    try {
      const response = await submitPulseResponse(payload, token);
      if (response.data.success) {
        // Call updateGraphPercentages directly with newPulseData
        const newPulseData = response.data.data;
        console.log(response.data.data.total);
        updateGraphPercentages(newPulseData);
        setHasVoted(true);
        setShowGraph(true);

        // New line to indicate a response has been submitted successfully
        setResponseSubmitted(true); // Set this to true to trigger useEffect

        const updatedVotedNewsIds = [
          ...(cookies.UserData?.VotedNewsIds?.split(',') || []),
          String(currentNewsId),
        ];
        // cookies.set(
        //   'UserData',
        //   { ...cookies.UserData, VotedNewsIds: updatedVotedNewsIds.join(',') },
        //   { path: '/' }
        // );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting pulse response:', error);
    }
  };

  console.log('After Submitpulse responseCount:', responseCount);

  console.log('Rendered responseCount:', responseCount);

  return (
    <div className={`pulse-check ${hasVoted ? 'show-graph' : ''}`}>
      <div className="header">
        <img src={pulseIcon} alt="Pulse Icon" className="pulse-icon" />
        {question && <span className="title">Pulse Check</span>}
        <img src={counterIcon} alt="Counter Icon" className="counter-icon" />
        <span className="response-count">{responseCount}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        {question && <p className="question">{question}</p>}
        {isUserLoggedIn && showGraph === true && responseCount > 0 ? ( // Show the graph only who hasVoted
          // Render the graph
          <div className="graph">
            {/* Tooltip integration starts here */}
            {options[0] && optionOnePercent > 0 && optionOnePercent !== null && (
              <Tooltip title={toolTipText} arrow>
                <div className="graph-bar option-one" style={{ width: `${optionOnePercent}%` }}>
                  {optionOnePercent}%
                </div>
              </Tooltip>
            )}
            {options[1] && optionTwoPercent > 0 && optionTwoPercent !== null && (
              <Tooltip title={toolTipText} arrow>
                <div className="graph-bar option-two" style={{ width: `${optionTwoPercent + 1}%` }}>
                  {optionTwoPercent}%
                </div>
              </Tooltip>
            )}
            {/* Tooltip integration ends here */}
          </div>
        ) : (
          // Render the options for all users; interaction will be limited for non-logged-in users
          <div className="buttons">
            {options.map((option, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                className={`response-button ${index === 0 ? 'first' : 'second'}`}
                onClick={(e) => handleResponse(e, option)}
              >
                {option}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PulseCheck;
```

Comment: Hi, please add your code to the question itself, not off-site.

Comment: @NickParsons sure I have done the same, thanks!

Comment: What do your logs show? Is `console.log('Total value: ', total);` showing the correct total?

Comment: Yes it does, it shows the correct total however it goes in a loop and console.logs multiple times and this is when things get messed up. Even if the responseCount gets set to the latest possible total value from api it again gets change due to this looping. Unsure why is this happening.

Comment: You can check the screenshot here if possible => https://privatebin.support-tools.com/?49770aa7ab214630#nqQ76m57YLUtH1hfsIlXTn4gFJgTae9Z6f9NgA5ZqTA=

Comment: @NickParsons could you please help me in this issue/bug I mentioned above? Many thanks!

Comment: Hey, I've had a look but nothing stands out to me, I might have to take a look again when I have more time. Regarding the pastebin screenshot, those logs seem to show that the response count is being updated correctly from 1 to 2. You mentioned that some sort of "looping" is occurring but I'm not too clear on what you mean by that exactly. It would be best if you could create a [mre] of the issue if possible (so that we could tun a minified example of the issue in a codesanbox for example) to help debug.

Comment: Also if you're getting into a loop, that may suggest that your `useEffect`s  are firing again. Try and add logs to your `useEffect`s that call `setResponseCount` and make sure they aren't unintentionally firing when you don't want them to. Also, your logs at the top-level of your component (such as `console.log('Rendered responseCount:', responseCount);`, etc.) will all show the same value for `responseCount`, so I suggest just keeping one of these to reduce the noise in the logging. You can also temporarily disable `React.StrictMode` to further reduce the noise in the logs while you debug.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response and sure @NickParsons here's the minimal reproducible example(MRE) in below URL I also have mentioned the explanation of MRE below: https://privatebin.support-tools.com/?a3ec8ad5269490b0#b39UEF5t4FyQl4RaF9sSduhLZ5Ee/eEqyz2y5jxS6Fs=

Comment: Thanks for providing a minimal example - It doesn't seem to _reproduce_ the issue you're describing though ([runnable example](https://jsfiddle.net/u2ckxqsL/))

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to useEffect being called multiple times post responseCount is set after the Api response's newTotal.
I restricted the call of useEffect by paying attention to it's dependency array and removing the unnecessary dependencies added which caused the useEffect to trigger after the handleresponse function.

Below is the correct code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import './PulseCheck.scss';
import { handleEventsForAnalytics } from '../../utils/helper';
import eventBus from '../../utils/eventBus';
import pulseIcon from '../../assets/images/icons/Medflix/pulse.svg';
import counterIcon from '../../assets/images/icons/Medflix/counter.svg';
import { submitPulseResponse } from '../../services/service';

const PulseCheck = ({
  question,
  options = [],
  page,
  variant,
  data,
  eachData,
  pulseData,
  toolTipText,
}) => {
  const [responseCount, setResponseCount] = useState(0);
  const [showGraph, setShowGraph] = useState(false);
  const [optionOnePercent, setOptionOnePercent] = useState(0);
  const [optionTwoPercent, setOptionTwoPercent] = useState(0);
  const [cookies] = useCookies(['UserData']);
  const [hasVoted, setHasVoted] = useState(false);
  const [responseSubmitted, setResponseSubmitted] = useState(false); // New state to track response submission

  const token = cookies?.UserData?.token;
  const objectId = cookies?.UserData?.ObjectID;
  const isUserLoggedIn = !!token && !!objectId; // Check if user is logged in
  const currentNewsId = eachData?.fields?.Id?.value || eachData?.Id;
  const votedNewsIds = cookies.UserData?.VotedNewsIds?.split(',') || [];

  // Simplified useEffect for responseCount logging
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('responseCount updated to:', responseCount);
  }, [responseCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if user has already voted

    if (pulseData && Array.isArray(pulseData.data)) {
      // Find the pulse data for the current news ID
      const currentPulseData = pulseData.data.find((d) => d.newsId === String(currentNewsId));

      if (currentPulseData) {
        setResponseCount(currentPulseData.total); // Directly update responseCount
        const hasUserVoted = votedNewsIds.includes(String(currentNewsId));
        if (hasUserVoted === true) {
          updateGraphPercentages(currentPulseData);
          setShowGraph(true);
        }
      }
    }
    // setHasVoted(true); // Assuming presence of pulseData indicates voting status
  }, [pulseData]);

  // New useEffect hook to handle graph rendering upon response submission
  useEffect(() => {
    if (responseSubmitted && pulseData) {
      setShowGraph(true);
      setResponseSubmitted(false);
    }
  }, [responseSubmitted, pulseData]); // Depend on responseSubmitted and pulseData

  // Function to update the graph percentages
  const updateGraphPercentages = ({ optionOneCount, optionTwoCount, total }) => {
    if (total > 0) {
      const calculatedOptionOnePercent = ((optionOneCount / total) * 100).toFixed(1);
      const calculatedOptionTwoPercent = ((optionTwoCount / total) * 100).toFixed(1);

      setOptionOnePercent(calculatedOptionOnePercent);
      setOptionTwoPercent(calculatedOptionTwoPercent);
      // If one of the options has all the votes (100%), set the other option's percentage to null
      if (calculatedOptionOnePercent === 100) {
        setOptionTwoPercent(null);
      } else if (calculatedOptionTwoPercent === 100) {
        setOptionOnePercent(null);
      }
    }
  };

  // Function to handle analytics event
  const handleClick = (event, ev, item_location, type, title, url) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let analyticsData = {
      type,
      title,
      url,
    };
    handleEventsForAnalytics(event, ev, analyticsData, item_location);
  };

  // Function to handle response and show graph
  const handleResponse = async (event, option) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check if the user is not logged in
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
      // Prevent further action and show the login popup
      eventBus.dispatch('validateUser', { isLoggedIn: false, Msg: 'NotSignedIn' });
      return;
    }

    if (hasVoted) {
      // If the user has already voted, don't allow voting
      console.log('User has already voted');
      return;
    }

    const newsId = eachData?.fields?.Id?.value || eachData?.Id || pulseData?.data?.newsId;

    if (!newsId) {
      // Handle the case where newsId is not defined
      console.error('No valid newsId to send');
      return;
    }

    const selectedOption = option === options[0] ? 'OPTION_ONE' : 'OPTION_TWO';

    // Payload to be sent to the backend
    const payload = {
      newsId: newsId,
      objectId: objectId,
      selectedOption: selectedOption,
    };

    // console.log(`Before updating, responseCount: ${responseCount}, pulseData:`, pulseData);

    // Use the service function to send the payload to the backend
    try {
      const response = await submitPulseResponse(payload, token);
      if (response.data.success) {
        const newTotal = response.data.data.total;

        const { optionOneCount, optionTwoCount } = response.data.data;

        // Update the local state with the new data
        setResponseCount(newTotal);
        updateGraphPercentages({ optionOneCount, optionTwoCount, total: newTotal });
        setHasVoted(true);
        setShowGraph(true);
        setResponseSubmitted(true);

        // console.log(
        //   `After updating, newTotal: ${newTotal}, option counts: ${optionOneCount}, ${optionTwoCount}`
        // );

        const updatedVotedNewsIds = [
          ...(cookies.UserData?.VotedNewsIds?.split(',') || []),
          String(currentNewsId),
        ];
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting pulse response:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`pulse-check ${hasVoted ? 'show-graph' : ''}`}>
      <div className="header">
        <img src={pulseIcon} alt="Pulse Icon" className="pulse-icon" />
        {question && <span className="title">Pulse Check</span>}
        <img src={counterIcon} alt="Counter Icon" className="counter-icon" />
        <span className="response-count">{responseCount}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        {question && <p className="question">{question}</p>}
        {isUserLoggedIn && showGraph === true && responseCount > 0 ? ( // Show the graph only who hasVoted
          // Render the graph
          <div className="graph">
            {/* Tooltip integration starts here */}
            {options[0] && optionOnePercent > 0 && optionOnePercent !== null && (
              <Tooltip title={toolTipText} arrow>
                <div className="graph-bar option-one" style={{ width: `${optionOnePercent}%` }}>
                  {optionOnePercent}%
                </div>
              </Tooltip>
            )}
            {options[1] && optionTwoPercent > 0 && optionTwoPercent !== null && (
              <Tooltip title={toolTipText} arrow>
                <div className="graph-bar option-two" style={{ width: `${optionTwoPercent + 1}%` }}>
                  {optionTwoPercent}%
                </div>
              </Tooltip>
            )}
            {/* Tooltip integration ends here */}
          </div>
        ) : (
          // Render the options for all users; interaction will be limited for non-logged-in users
          <div className="buttons">
            {options.map((option, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                className={`response-button ${index === 0 ? 'first' : 'second'}`}
                onClick={(e) => handleResponse(e, option)}
              >
                {option}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PulseCheck;
```